# What's the difference between context.Get() and its generic version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

I'm trying to get familiar with OWIN and there are a lot of things that confuse me. For example, in partial startup.cs class I register context callback via

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

What's the difference? Why do we need that generic method?

I can get that context like this:

```
context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
```

What's the difference between the Get and GetUserManager methods? Why can't I just call context.Get for ApplicationUserManager?

Comment: What is `context`? dbContext, OWIN context, HttpContext?

Comment: Owin context, i thought it's obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between `Get<UserManager>` and `GetUserManager<UserManager>`

Here's the source code for both...

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Retrieves an object from the OwinContext using a key based on the AssemblyQualified type name
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Get<T>(this IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        return context.Get<T>(GetKey(typeof (T)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get the user manager from the context
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TManager"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TManager GetUserManager<TManager>(this IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        return context.Get<TManager>();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the Q, *what's the difference between Get() and the generic version*.

Comment: So if there is no difference, I can easily call context.Get<ApplicationUserManager>() instead of context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>? So why do we need a separate method for only getting a UserManager?

Comment: Yes. You dont need a separate method and you can obviously interchange them. As for the reasoning for this I'm not sure. Could be something left over from an earlier version of Identity.

Comment: @Shoe is `Get<T>` not part of Owin? and `GetUserManager` is from Identity? I mean they are from different assemblies and used by different components?

Comment: Thank you, finally I got it ;)

Comment: @trailmax `Get<T>(string)` is part of OWIN `Get<T>()` and `GetUserManager<T>()` are some owin extensions in the identity namespace.

Comment: @Shoe in that case having 2 methods make sense. I'd include that in the answer as a reason behind having 2 similar methods.

Comment: @trailmax The two `Get<T>` methods make sense. I'm not sure why `GetUserManager<T>` exists